# ASP.NET core form submit post method is not working while passing view model

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, post, web-applications

I am creating a login page for which I am sending email and password to controller using form submit post method. My code is as follows:

**Html**

```
@model DishedendsCommon.Models.Login.LoginViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "dishedends login";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="~/css/login.css" asp-append-version="true" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>


    <div class="login">
        <div class="login__form">

            <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post">
                @*<span class="material-icons">lock</span>*@
                <img src="~/image/logo-3.png" alt="Alternate Text" />

                <input id="ipEmail" type="text" Asp-for="Email" placeholder="Email" required />
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Email"></span>

                <input id="ipPassword" type="password" asp-for="Password" placeholder="Password" required />
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Password"></span>

                <button type="submit" value="Login">Login</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
namespace DishedendsWeb.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(model.Email);
                    return View();
                }
            }
            catch (ApiCallException ex)
            {
                // return HandleLoginPageError(ex, model);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Email Address
        /// </summary>
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your e-mail address.")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the correct email address.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Password
        /// </summary>
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your password.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Language
        /// </summary>
        public string Language { get; set; } = "en";

        /// <summary>
        /// FirstLogin
        /// </summary>
        public bool FirstLogin { get; set; } = false;
}
```

When I click on submit button, I get the following output:

[image]

I don't know, why it is not hitting the controller. Can you please help me.

**Update**
FYI: I have created ASP .NET Core Web App (MVC)

I have created web app and web API project in same solution (Also includes separate DB project).
After adding the reference of API project in my web app project I am facing this problem.

[image]

As I remove the API project reference, the above code works. I don't know why is it happening? Can someone help?

Comment: Any specific reason to redirect to /api/account/login endpoint?

Comment: Try adding `[FromForm]` attribute on your `post ` method: `public ActionResult Login([FromForm]LoginViewModel model)`

Comment: why did you use web-api template?

Comment: @RahulSharma I tried but it is not working. I have created MVC web app and added one reference of API project. isn't it the reason?

Comment: @AbhiSingh See the url in your posted screenshot. It is pointing to `/api` so you need to check how you have done the configuration of your routes. And it could be because of using wrong namespace - for example, you are using the api project namespace

Comment: @RahulSharma I have the default configuration for route, I have not changed anything.
I have created one API project separately, after adding reference of that API project in my WebApp project, I am facing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The 415 error code indicates that you didn't set the  correct Content-Type in header.And I checked your url,it seems that you created a web api project.You could try to modify your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login([FromForm]LoginViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(model.Email);
                    return View();
                }
            }
            catch (ApiCallException ex)
            {
                // return HandleLoginPageError(ex, model);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Or you could create a MVC project

Comment: I have created MVC project but I have added project reference for different API project.

Comment: After adding the reference of API project, my URL is adding api. Can you help me to resolve this?

Comment: I tried adding reference of API project in MVC project,but it worked well.Could you share you codes on Github so that we can figure out what's wrong?